# Capture ORACLE query causing overflow on table

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm facing an issue where a Java process (that I have no control over) is inserting rows into a table and causing an overflow. I have no way of intercepting the queries, and the exception raised by ORACLE is not informative. It only mentions an overflow, but not which column it's happening on.

I'd like to know which query is causing this overflow as well as the values being inserted.

I tried creating a trigger BEFORE INSERT on the table that copies the rows into another temporary table that I can later read, however it looks like the trigger is not being run when the overflow happens.

Trigger syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OVERFLOW_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
    ON VICTIM_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into QUERIES_DUMP values (
        :old.COL1, :old.COL2, :old.COL3, 
        :old.COL4, :old.COL5, :old.COL6, 
        :old.COL7, :old.COL8, :old.COL9, 
        :old.COL10, :old.COL11, :old.COL12
    );
END;
/
```

The table QUERIES_DUMP has the same structure of the failing table however with the NUMBER and VARCHAR2 columns pushed to their max capacity. I'm hoping to get a list of queries and then find out which ones are breaking the rules.

Is it expected for a trigger to not run in case of an overflow, even if set to run before insert?

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Prod
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

**EDIT1:**

The error being thrown is:

```
Description: Error while query: INSERT INTO 
...
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

What I know is that there are no wrong types being inserted anywhere. It's most probably the length of one of the numeric fields, but they're numerous and the insertion process takes more than an hour, so I can't brute force my way into guessing the column.

I've thought about backing up the table and creating a new victim_table with larger columns, but the process actually inserts into a lot of other tables as well in a complex datamodel and the DB has somewhat sensitive information so I can't endanger its consistency by moving things around.

I tried an INSTEAD OF trigger but ORACLE doesn't seem to accept an INSTEAD OF for inserts on a table.

I added logging on the JDBC layer, but the queries I got did not have values, only '?'

```
Description: Error while query: INSERT INTO VICTIM_TABLE ( . . . ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: You need to do your insert in an [autonomous transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm). It's getting rolled back.

Comment: Turn on tracing, then run TKPROF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specific error (including an ORA-xxxxx error number is always greatly appreciated).

If the problem is that the Java application is trying to insert a value that cannot be converted to the table's data type, that error would be expected to be thrown before the trigger could run.  Data type validations have to happen before the trigger can execute.

Imagine what would happen if data type validations happened after the trigger ran.  If the Java app passed an invalid value for, say, `col1`, then inside the trigger, `:new.col1` would have a data type of whatever `col1` has in the underlying table but would have an invalid value.  Any reference to that field, therefore, would need to result in an error being raised-- you couldn't plausibly log an invalid value to your table.

Are you sure that you can't intercept the queries somehow?  For example, if you renamed `victim_table` to `victim_table_base`, created a view named `victim_table` with larger data types, and then defined an `instead of` trigger on the view that validated the data and inserted it into the table, you could identify which values were invalid.  Alternately, since your Java application is using JDBC (presumably) to interact with the database, you should be able to enable logging at the JDBC layer to see the parameter values that are being passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. Can you go through my question again? I updated it with the suggestions you gave.

Comment: @OdayMansour - If you want to use the `instead of` trigger approach, you'd need to rename the table, create a view, and define the trigger on the view.  You can't define an `instead of` trigger on a table.